# Capistrano v3 deploy failed on git rev-parse --short HEAD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, webfaction, capistrano3

Hi this is the error that is appearing when I'm deploying using Capistrano 3 with a Rails 4 app to a Webfaction server.

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: cd 
/home/username/webapps/app/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD stdout: Nothing written
cd /home/username/webapps/app/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD stderr: Nothing written>
```

My git repository is inside webfaction, I created it as --bare repository, don't know if that changes things. I set it up the URL like this in my capistrano file:

```
set :repo_url, '/home/username/webapps/git_app/repos/myrepo.git'
```

Any additional info that you may need, please ask

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you run `cd /home/username/webapps/app/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD` on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around this issue with this procedure, I don't believe it's the correct one but it helped me through:

I copied all the files (the git config files) from my repo: /home/username/webapps/git_app/repos/my_git.git/

to the mirror repo that Capistrano builds in Webfaction: /home/username/webapps/git_app/repo

Like this:

```
cp -a /home/username/webapps/git_app/repos/my_git.git/. /home/username/webapps/git_app/repo
```